# Pulling minute bar data with bar() function in Rbbg (RBloomberg) package in R

Tags: r, bloomberg

I am fairly new to the Rbbg package, so please excuse any ignorance on my part, however I am wondering if it is possible to pull more than ~25 days of minute bar data using the `bar()` function.  I've found I can't pull more than 25 or 26 days worth of data and am wondering if I am doing something wrong, or if it is just not possible.

Here is the code I am using:

```
#install.packages("rJava")
#install.packages("Rbbg", repos="http://r.findata.org")
#install.packages("timeDate")

library(rJava)
library(Rbbg)
library(timeDate)

conn <- blpConnect()

weekdays = timeSequence(from = (Sys.Date()-38), to = (Sys.Date()-1), by = "day")[isWeekday(timeSequence(from = (Sys.Date()-38), to = (Sys.Date()-1), by = "day"))]

date_time=numeric()
volume=numeric()
for(i in 1:length(weekdays)){

start.date <- paste(weekdays[i],"13:30:00.000")
end.date <- paste(weekdays[i],"20:00:00.000")

raw=bar(conn, "GOOG US Equity", "TRADE", start.date, end.date, "1")

date_time=append(date_time,raw$time)
volume=append(volume,raw$volume)
}

date.time <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(date_time),'T',fixed=TRUE)))
use=data.frame("date"=format(as.Date(date.time$X1), "%m/%d/%Y"),"time"=date.time$X2,"volume"=raw$volume)

blpDisconnect(conn)
```

This works fine and pulls data from the trading days in the past 3.5 weeks.  Now, if I try to change the 38 to a greater number in the line `weekdays = timeSequence(from = (Sys.Date()-38), to = (Sys.Date()-1), by = "day")[isWeekday(timeSequence(from = (Sys.Date()-38), to = (Sys.Date()-1), by = "day"))]`, I get the following error: `Error in matrix.data[, 1] : subscript out of bounds` when I try running the above script.

Is it the case that the API can only pull about 3.5 weeks of minute bar data?  Or am I doing something incorrect?  Ideally, I would like to have at least 100 trading days worth of data.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Bloomberg delivers six months of intraday data. If I use the function BarData from our R package RbbgExtension (can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/pgarnry/RbbgExtension)) on Google you get 1-minute bars six months back. Just to clarify why we convert times to GMT it is because European equities trade across multiple time zones but starts at the same time, so to get data which is time aligned we convert prices into GMT.

```
> goog.bar <- BarData(tickers = "GOOG US",
+                     type = "Equity",
+                     start.date.time = "2014-01-01 09:30:00",
+                     end.date.time = "2015-01-21 16:05:00",
+                     time.zone = "America/New_York",
+                     interval = "1")
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) 
rJava Version 0.9-6 
Rbbg Version 0.5.2 
Java environment initialized successfully.
Looking for most recent blpapi3.jar file...
Adding C:\blp\API\APIv3\JavaAPI\v3.7.1.1\lib\blpapi3.jar to Java classpath
Bloomberg API Version 3.7.1.1 
> head(goog.bar)
                       open   high    low   close numEvents volume
2014-07-10 13:30:00 565.910 566.85 565.01 565.745       142  38862
2014-07-10 13:31:00 565.500 566.06 565.01 565.190        49   7606
2014-07-10 13:32:00 565.110 566.70 565.11 566.350        49   6878
2014-07-10 13:33:00 566.390 566.60 566.00 566.600        34   4473
2014-07-10 13:34:00 566.470 566.48 565.65 565.850        52   6365
2014-07-10 13:35:00 565.775 566.45 565.55 566.050       107  14513
Warning message:
timezone of object (GMT) is different than current timezone (). 
> tail(goog.bar)
                      open    high    low   close numEvents volume
2015-01-21 20:54:00 518.00 518.520 518.00 518.275       135  15492
2015-01-21 20:55:00 518.31 518.500 518.22 518.230       116  14048
2015-01-21 20:56:00 518.23 518.374 518.22 518.350        83   9696
2015-01-21 20:57:00 518.35 518.390 518.18 518.250        99  12289
2015-01-21 20:58:00 518.25 518.640 518.20 518.420       116  15353
2015-01-21 20:59:00 518.39 518.390 517.80 518.040       309 101288
Warning message:
timezone of object (GMT) is different than current timezone ().
```

However, I am able to get you error. If I don't specify an actual end date/time, then the output is as you highlight. So the point is to be precise about the end date/time.

```
> goog.bar <- BarData(tickers = "GOOG US",
+                     type = "Equity",
+                     start.date.time = "2014-01-01 09:30:00",
+                     time.zone = "America/New_York",
+                     interval = "1")
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) 
rJava Version 0.9-6 
Rbbg Version 0.5.2 
Java environment initialized successfully.
Looking for most recent blpapi3.jar file...
Adding C:\blp\API\APIv3\JavaAPI\v3.7.1.1\lib\blpapi3.jar to Java classpath
Bloomberg API Version 3.7.1.1 
> head(goog.bar)
                       open   high    low   close numEvents volume
2014-07-10 13:30:00 565.910 566.85 565.01 565.745       142  38862
2014-07-10 13:31:00 565.500 566.06 565.01 565.190        49   7606
2014-07-10 13:32:00 565.110 566.70 565.11 566.350        49   6878
2014-07-10 13:33:00 566.390 566.60 566.00 566.600        34   4473
2014-07-10 13:34:00 566.470 566.48 565.65 565.850        52   6365
2014-07-10 13:35:00 565.775 566.45 565.55 566.050       107  14513
Warning message:
timezone of object (GMT) is different than current timezone (). 
> tail(goog.bar)
                       open    high     low   close numEvents volume
2014-08-15 19:54:00 573.445 573.695 573.445 573.620        30   4428
2014-08-15 19:55:00 573.675 573.710 573.550 573.570        54   6496
2014-08-15 19:56:00 573.617 573.715 573.340 573.430       102  12067
2014-08-15 19:57:00 573.585 573.600 573.330 573.375        36   4300
2014-08-15 19:58:00 573.375 573.730 572.920 573.000       181  22467
2014-08-15 19:59:00 572.990 573.500 572.780 573.480       158  43183
Warning message:
timezone of object (GMT) is different than current timezone ().
```